# Enthought Canopy Psycopg2 Install

Tags: python, psycopg2, enthought, canopy

I'm running into problems installing Psycopg2 using the package manager of Enthought Canopy. I get an error that says the following:

```
Action: install Psycopg2Database-0.2.0-1.egg 
The package manager has encountered error 
Loop in dependency graph 
[u'DatabasePipe-2.2.1-1.egg', u'PipeStack-0.5.3-1.egg', u'Psycopg2Database-0.2.0-1.egg', u'SQLite3Database-0.2.0-1.egg']
```

I tried installing the packages listed in the error message, but they also don't install either. Seems like there is something messed up in the dependencies. I have tried installing both under Mac OS and Win 7, same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Psycopg2Database package is not in [the Canopy / EPD repository](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/package-index/).

Rather, it is in the "Community" (PyPi mirror) repo (marked by the "PyPI" logo in the Package Manager), which contains 11,000 untested ("as is") packages. Most of the packages are current and we are in the process of updating the rest, as well as keeping it updated from now on. Please note that we do not test for nor necessarily provide dependencies.

Meanwhile, this may help:
"[Installing external packages into Canopy Python](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-external-packages-into-Canopy-Python)"

Comment: Note that the psycopg2 package (likely what OP wants) is not the same package as psycopg2database (the latter is quite old and not downloaded very often). This was a source of confusion for a colleague who read this post.